# In aws cdk, how to connect lambda in pipeline to stack written after pipeline stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pipeline, aws-cdk

Im using this [code](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/master/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline-actions/test/integ.lambda-deployed-through-codepipeline.lit.ts) to create pipeline to lambda.
I was able to create stack in the app with vpc before the the pipeline and use it for the lambda, but when Im trying to put stack with gateway in app after the pipeline and connect the lambda to it as authorizer, it trying to deploy lambda stack and Im getting `failed: Error: The following CloudFormation Parameters are missing a value: FirstLambdaLambdaSourceBucketNameParameter4BB158A3, FirstLambdaLambdaSourceObjectKeyParameter65E28DA5`.

I understand it happens because of this line `const lambdaCode = lambda.Code.fromCfnParameters();` and filling of the parameters happen in the pipeline on `lambdaCode.assign(lambdaBuildOutput.s3Location)` and not in the lambda.

Is there any solution instead of putting all code in the pipeline?

## EDIT:

**code example:**

cdk.ts:

```js
const lambdaPipelineStack = new LambdaPipelineStack(app, 'LambdaPipelineStack')
const connections = new ConnectionsStack(app, 'ConnectionsStack', {
    lambdaPipelineStack
})
```

pipeline + lambda:

```js
declare const vpc: ec2.Vpc

export class LambdaPipelineStack extends Stack {
    public readonly lambdasDeployStage: LambdasDeployStage
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: InfraStackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props)

        const pipeline = new CodePipeline(this, 'lambdasPipeline', {
            codeBuildDefaults: {
                rolePolicy: [
                    new PolicyStatement({
                        actions: ['sts:AssumeRole'],
                        resources: ['*'],
                        conditions: {
                            StringEquals: {
                                'iam:ResourceTag/aws-cdk:bootstrap-role': 'lookup'
                            }
                        }
                    })
                ]
            },
            dockerEnabledForSynth: true,
            selfMutation: true,
            synth: new ShellStep('Synth', {
                input: CodePipelineSource.connection('ORG/cdk', 'master', {
                    connectionArn: CONNECTION_ARN
                }),
                additionalInputs: {
                    spend: CodePipelineSource.connection('ORG/REPO', 'dev', {
                        connectionArn: CONNECTION_ARN
                    })
                },
                commands: ['npm ci', 'npm run build', 'npx cdk synth'],
                env: { vpcId: vpc.vpcId }
            })
        })

        this.lambdasDeployStage = new LambdasDeployStage(this, 'LambdaDeploy', props)
        pipeline.addStage(lambdasDeployStage)
    }
}
```

```js
export class LambdasDeployStage extends Stage {
    public readonly lambdaStack: LambdasStack
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props)

        this.lambdaStack = new LambdasStack(this, 'LambdaStack', props)
    }
}
```

```js
export class LambdasStack extends Stack {
    public readonly authorizerLambda: nodeLambda.NodejsFunction
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props)

        const vpcId = process.env.vpcId
        this.authorizerLambda = new nodeLambda.NodejsFunction(this, 'FirstLambda', {
            vpc: ec2.Vpc.fromLookup(this, 'Vpc', { vpcId }),
            vpcSubnets: {
                subnetType: SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED
            },
            entry: './lambda/functions/auth.js',
            handler: 'handler',
            runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_14_X
        })
    }
}
```

gateway:

```js
declare const localVpcLink: VpcLink
declare const cloudMapService: cloudmap.IService

export class ConnectionsStack extends Stack {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: ConnectionStackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props)

        // GATEWAY
        const httpApi = new apigwv2.HttpApi(this, 'httpGW', {})
        const integration = new HttpServiceDiscoveryIntegration(
            'integration',
            cloudMapService,
            { vpcLink: localVpcLink }
        )

        const authorizer = new HttpLambdaAuthorizer('lambda-auth', props.lambdaPipelineStack.lambdasDeployStage.lambdaStack.authorizerLambda,, { responseTypes: [HttpLambdaResponseType.SIMPLE] })

        httpApi.addRoutes({
            path: '/ql',
            methods: [HttpMethod.ANY],
            integration,
            authorizer
        })
    }
}
```

What you can see that I did bad in the this code is trying to add dependency from stage into App, and therefore getting `dependency cannot cross stage boundaries`. Im trying to understand what is the right way to connect pipeline with lambda stack into App stack (something I able to do with service pipeline).

Comment: The github code is optimised for _testing_ CDK constructs, not for production deployment. `lambda.Code.fromCfnParameters` is not a standard production idiom, for example.  It can be made to work, but is probably needlessly complex.  If you are looking for a pipeline reference implementation, try AWS's [cdk-workshop](https://cdkworkshop.com/20-typescript/70-advanced-topics/200-pipelines/3000-new-pipeline.html).

Comment: @fedonev
When trying the workshop example Im getting `dependency cannot cross stage boundaries` when trying to pass the vpc inside. I can solve it by passing it through env and do a lookup, but still it don't solve the main problem, how to pass the lambda back to the gateway in the app.

Comment: Words are great, but [code is better](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Could you add a minimal example to your question?  I am not clever enough to understand what your app structure is.

Comment: added a code, tried to make it short, hopes it is not too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding:  you want to deploy `ConnectionsStack` and `LambdasStack` in a pipeline.

When you deploy stacks with a pipeline, the stacks are children of a `cdk.Stage`, grandchildren of a `PipelineStack`, and great-granchildren of a `cdk.App`.   A pipeline can have many stages.  A stage can have many stacks.  Pipelines (like constructs generally) are meant to be modified and redeployed multiple times as requirements are added.  Compose your pipeline app with a `App > Pipeline Stack > Stage > Stacks`  hierarchy in mind.

Your top-level app definition is not in the OP, but my guess is you are not composing correctly.  Here's an idiomatic way to compose the pipeline:

(1) Add the pipeline stack as the app's entry point, [as in the workshop](https://cdkworkshop.com/20-typescript/70-advanced-topics/200-pipelines/1000-setting-up.html):

```js
// cdk.ts
const app = new cdk.App();
new LambdaPipelineStack(app, 'MyPipelineStack');
```

(2) Add the app's 2 stacks to the stage:

```js
// deploy stage
export class LambdasDeployStage extends Stage {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props)

        // refactor the lambdas stack property to expose the authorizerLambda Function
        // ConnectionStack should take a authorizerLambda: Function  as a prop instead of the whole lambda stack
        const { authorizerLambda } = new LambdasStack(this, 'LambdaStack', props)
        new ConnectionsStack(this, 'ConnectionsStack', {...props, authorizerLambda})
    }
}
```

(3) Add the stage to the pipeline: your `LambdaPipelineStack` is composing correctly!